Fitting S-curve to my data - unable to adjust parameters to steepen curve
I am working with the following code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def logistic(x, a, b, c, d=0):
    """
    Logistic function that maps x to a value between two asymptotes d and c.

    Parameters:
    - x: The independent variable or array of variables.
    - a: Defines the steepness of the curve.
    - b: Midpoint of the function where the maximum growth occurs.
    - c: The maximum value (upper asymptote) of the function.
    - d: The minimum value (lower asymptote) of the function, defaults to 0.

    Returns:
    - The calculated logistic value(s).
    """
    return d + (c - d) / (1 + np.exp(-a * (x - b)))

# Define the data
x = np.array([-4.49,-5.53,-6.66,-4.82,-7.01,-8.62,-9.86,-11.64,-12.41,-3.06,-4.48,-7.86,-3.09,
              -11.21,-2.01,-0.47,-4.60,-1.72,-4.21,-1.04,-2.90,-20.91,-2.47,-4.16,-2.81,-2.62,
              -2.57,-5.81,-7.34,-5.67,12.16,-6.82,-3.63,-20.75,-3.05,3.22,-0.91,-10.40,-3.66,
              -3.90,-4.69,60.39,-6.88,12.83,22.23,12.00,42.54,63.11,30.29,28.07,
              10.11,-2.99,2.18,1.14,1.49,-9.55])

y = np.array([0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.23,7.01,10.00,15.37,16.93,17.79,
              18.01,18.06,18.61,20.60,21.22,24.40,28.09,30.28,30.56,34.33,46.07,47.64,51.50,
              58.96,64.92,68.02,75.59,76.65,80.39,83.19,83.76,85.83,87.03,87.84,88.01,92.55,
              93.84,95.42,96.10,96.19,100.00,100.00,100.00,100.00,100.00,100.00,100.00,
              100.00,100.00,100.00,100.00,100.00])

# Use curve_fit to estimate the logistic function parameters
p0 = [1, 0, 1] # initial guesses for parameters a, b, and c
params, pcov = curve_fit(logistic, x, y, p0)

# Generate values for the x-axis to plot the curve
x_fit = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 1000)

# Generate predictions for the y-axis using the estimated parameters
y_fit = logistic(x_fit, *params)

# Plot the data and the curve fit
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit, 'r-', label='S-curve fit')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

the S-curve just doesn't fit the data correctly, I want it to be steeper and the limits as 0, 1, reflecting something more like in the image I have provided

but every time I adjust my parameters the curve completely breaks and looks like a horizontal line
could somebody help me with this?

It give me a warning "RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
return d + (c - d) / (1 + np.exp(-a * (x - b)))" which may get worse as slope increases

The data look strange, almost with a negative slope (so not a function).  Have you tested your code on a simpler data set?

OP, I think it would help others understand what's going on if you say a few words about what these data represent. Is it experimental data of some kind? If so, what?

There's nothing particularly wrong with your code - it's your DATA that has got mangled somehow.
Add the line
x = np.sort( x )

after setting x and before fitting. Then you get (full code at the bottom):
a, b, c =  1.0179736944407503 -3.9145795490586286 100.05506778222558


For reference - the amended code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def logistic(x, a, b, c, d=0):
    """
    Logistic function that maps x to a value between two asymptotes d and c.

    Parameters:
    - x: The independent variable or array of variables.
    - a: Defines the steepness of the curve.
    - b: Midpoint of the function where the maximum growth occurs.
    - c: The maximum value (upper asymptote) of the function.
    - d: The minimum value (lower asymptote) of the function, defaults to 0.

    Returns:
    - The calculated logistic value(s).
    """
    return d + (c - d) / (1 + np.exp(-a * (x - b)))

# Define the data
x = np.array([-4.49,-5.53,-6.66,-4.82,-7.01,-8.62,-9.86,-11.64,-12.41,-3.06,-4.48,-7.86,-3.09,
              -11.21,-2.01,-0.47,-4.60,-1.72,-4.21,-1.04,-2.90,-20.91,-2.47,-4.16,-2.81,-2.62,
              -2.57,-5.81,-7.34,-5.67,12.16,-6.82,-3.63,-20.75,-3.05,3.22,-0.91,-10.40,-3.66,
              -3.90,-4.69,60.39,-6.88,12.83,22.23,12.00,42.54,63.11,30.29,28.07,
              10.11,-2.99,2.18,1.14,1.49,-9.55])

y = np.array([0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.23,7.01,10.00,15.37,16.93,17.79,
              18.01,18.06,18.61,20.60,21.22,24.40,28.09,30.28,30.56,34.33,46.07,47.64,51.50,
              58.96,64.92,68.02,75.59,76.65,80.39,83.19,83.76,85.83,87.03,87.84,88.01,92.55,
              93.84,95.42,96.10,96.19,100.00,100.00,100.00,100.00,100.00,100.00,100.00,
              100.00,100.00,100.00,100.00,100.00])

x = np.sort( x )

# Use curve_fit to estimate the logistic function parameters
p0 = [1, 0, 100] # initial guesses for parameters a, b, and c
params, pcov = curve_fit(logistic, x, y, p0)
print( "a, b, c = ", *params )

# Generate values for the x-axis to plot the curve
x_fit = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 1000)

# Generate predictions for the y-axis using the estimated parameters
y_fit = logistic(x_fit, *params)

# Plot the data and the curve fit
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit, 'r-', label='S-curve fit')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


This looks great - but are you not jumbling up the X and Y values in the data points by doing that? The X and Y np arrays are in the order that they relate to each other, but by sorting the X array you are assigning the incorrect Y values to them...

Certainly, I'm not keeping them in their current pairing. But I think your x-array data has already been jumbled up - you need to go back and look at where it comes from. Just look at the order of x values in your array: it is highly unlikely that your independent variable is going to be mis-ordered like that. By contrast, your y-data seems to have been treated more gently. I do recommend: GO BACK AND CHECK YOUR SOURCE OF DATA.

There are other factors at play which means the data is not perfect - I mean, what data is? I am happy with my data, the CAPS aren't necessary. All I want is to know why changing the parameters in my code breaks the S-curve

There's not much more that I can add - the original x-array ordering is almost impossible. No realistic switch-type curve could fit that original data. If you sort your independent-variable data then the fit is almost perfect. We've all accidentally jumbled things at one time or another. Can you go back to your raw experimental measurements and just check a few points?

Again, I can assure you I am happy with my data. I am just trying to adjust a parameter in the code, I am not asking for input on my data, I am happy with an S-curve which I have already fitted through other means, I just am struggling to pythonise it, I can't accept an answer which changes my data first without knowing anything about it

Can you tell us the source of the data? Is it experimental data that you gathered yourself, or was it passed on from someone else. What, physically, is the data? Can you show us the "S-curve [that you] have already fitted through other means" and tell us what those "other means" are?

Please see my original question: "but every time I adjust my parameters the curve completely breaks and looks like a horizontal line".
I am asking a technical question on why changing my b parameter from say, 0, to 2, in my code, breaks the S curve which otherwise was being produced correctly (but was not fitting my data). This is a syntax question. I am not asking for your input on my data. If this bothers you please have a nice rest of your day

I've read your original question, @user24834135. But every time I look at it I'm more and more convinced that your x-array and y-array are simply out of sync. There doesn't seem much point in trying to deduce results from a flawed dataset. But, sure, I'll go away and "have a nice rest of day".

My impression is that your data would be better modelled with a step function.  Your model breaks down because it needs an infinite slope.
